# Split string by comma if previous character no \

Tags: java, string

I have a String, I need to split it with a comma, but if the previous character is \, then this part should not be splitted.

For example from `String str = "first,second\\,third,fourth"` i need `String[] strs = { "first", "second\\,third", "fourth" }`

Comment: When you found a ',', just check for '\' at position - 1, assuming that position > 0?

Comment: Have you tried looking for a CSV-parsing library yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
String str = "first,second\\,third,fourth";
String[] strs = s.split("(?<!\\\\),");
```

look at the java.utils.regex.Pattern documentation for an explanation.